# Usar JS para tirar o Hidden de uma div caso PHP autorize login

Tags: php, javascript, html, login

Boa tarde. Estou fazendo um simples sistema de login e estou tentando fazer com que uma div apareça com a mensagem "usuário e/ou senha incorreto(s)" caso o login seja recusado. O sistema de login está sendo feito com PHP, e para tirar o Hidden uso JS. Porém não faço a mínima ideia de como ter uma validação no JS para conseguir isso. (Lembrando que o PHP está em um arquivo separado e o JS dentro do HTML).

HTML - a div que eu desejo tirar o Hidden

```
<div class="div"><p>Usuário e/ou senha incorretos.</p>
```

PHP - login

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];
$foi = true;

if(($user == "abc") && ($pw == "abc")){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login-session'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['senha-session'] = $pw;
    header('Location: restrito/index-restrita.php');

    
}else{
    header("Location: index.php");
    $foi = false;
   
}
```

JS - script

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function mostrarErro(){
        var log = <?=$foi?>
        if(log == false){
        document.getElementByClassName('div').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 06/07/2020

Você não consegue passar a variável `$foi` para outra página mesmo que seja também PHP

Crie uma `$_SESSION['foi']` para passar valores para outra pagina

```
<?php
session_start();

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];

if(($user == "abc") && ($pw == "abc")){
    
    $_SESSION['login-session'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['senha-session'] = $pw;
    $_SESSION['foi'] = "foi";
    header('Location: restrito/index-restrita.php');

    
}else{

    $_SESSION['foi'] = "nao foi";
    header("Location: index.php"); 

}
?>
```

Página com a div

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<div class="div"><p>Usuario e/ou senha incorretos.</p></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function mostrarErro(){
        var log = "<?=$_SESSION['foi']?>";
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
        var elem = elems[0];
        if(log == "nao foi"){
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            elem.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

</script>
```

- Como você pode ver em *getElementsByClassName*, `Elements` é plural e, portanto, retorna uma coleção de todos os elementos com essa classe, não um único elemento. Você precisa indexar a coleção. Você pode acessar um determinado elemento ​​pelo índice. O índice começa em 0. Se você deseja o primeiro (ou único) elemento da coleção, use: `elems[0]`.

> OBS: `session_start();` deve ser a primeira linha do PHP

[image: suporte navegador]